# How to update the list of primary key of one column in one table into another table

Tags: sql-server

I just added a new data in `[Driver Table`], afterwards, I want to update `[Driver Dimension]` to get the value of every new data inserted in `[Driver Table]`. I'm using SQL Server 2012.

My code:

```
UPDATE [Driver Dimension] 
SET [DriverID] = [DriverID] 
FROM [Driver Table]
```

I get this error:

> Ambiguous column name 'DriverID'.

Both tables have a column which contains their respective primary keys called `[DriverID]`

EDIT:

Here is what I'm trying to achieve: I just inserted a new data into `[Driver Table]` with ID 11:

[image]

What I'm trying to achieve is, once I add no matter how many data in `[Driver Table]`, I will get the data and update my `[Driver Dimension]` table:

[image]

The `[Dimension table]` should be updated with the new `driverid` (11) and `firstname` I added from `[Driver table]` without having to do a separate `Insert` statement.

Comment: what else in common in those tables ?

Comment: I'm only trying to get the DriverID for now, but [Driver Table] also contains a column called [FirstName], which has the same data from [Driver Dimension].[DriverName]

Comment: Please add sample data for both tables and the desired result. sqlfiddle.com would be perfect.

Comment: Please see my latest edit, thanks!

Comment: Hint an update is not going to insert a row.  Why do you need to do this? This looks like a bad data design.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:
This should be working with your tables.

**UPDATE**

```
    INSERT INTO [Driver Table] (DriverId , FirstName, MiddleName, LastName)
    OUTPUT inserted.DriverId , inserted.FirstName 
    INTO [Dimension Table]
    VALUES (1 , 'Rhyme' , 'Santillan' , 'Aranas')
```

Comment: I used this and got this error: Additional information: The multi-part identifier "Driver Table.FirstName" could not be bound.

Comment: Here is the exact code I used from yours:

"Update [Driver Dimension] SET [Driver Dimension].[DriverName] = [Driver Table].[FirstName] FROM [Driver Dimension] Dimension JOIN [Driver Table] Driver ON Dimension.DriverID = Driver.DriverID";

Comment: You can't use the table name if you have alias, use the alias. "Update Dimension  SET Dimension.[DriverName] = Driver.[FirstName] FROM [Driver Dimension] Dimension JOIN [Driver Table] Driver ON Dimension.DriverID = Driver.DriverID"

Comment: I now know what's happening in your code, it updates the value of my DriverName code, but it doesn't add up the most recent data I added in [Driver Table]. I think it can be solved by adding a separate insert code to the data as well, but I wanted it to update the column fields itself using one line

Comment: @D.Trump123, From your question, I understood you want to update your dimension table from your driver table. if you have another scenario that you are having issues to accomplish, please add it to your question with expected results in both tables, and I'm sure we could help in a proper way.

Comment: You can achieve that by using the OUTPUT clause when inserting data into the driver table. I'll change the answer

Comment: Added Update to the answer

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Update [Driver Dimension] 
SET [DriverID] = ( SELECT TOP 1 [DriverID] 
                   From   [Driver Table] 
                   WHERE  [Driver Table].[FirstName] =[Driver Dimension].[DriverName] )
```

Comment: It gives me an error message: Additional information: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: are you sure that [Driver Table].[FirstName] =[Driver Dimension].[DriverName] exactly ??

Comment: yes, I just copied the entire column data earlier using this code:  

Update [Driver Dimension] SET [DriverName] = [Driver Table].[FirstName] FROM [Driver Table] WHERE [Driver Dimension].[DriverID] = [Driver Table].[DriverID], but it didn't get the latest input

Comment: I now know what's happening in your code, it updates the value of my DriverName code, but it doesn't add up the most recent data I added in [Driver Table]

Comment: I think it can be solved by adding a separate insert code to the data as well, but I wanted it to update the column fields itself using one line